# Why is my bean validation message not picked up?

Tags: java, jsf, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm defining some bean validation messages for later i18n.
This message should validate that an input is of type number / BigDecimal:

```
class Payment {
    @Digits(message = "test error msg", fraction = 2, integer = 13)
    private BigDecimal amount;
}

<p:inputText value="#{payment.amount}" />
```

Unfortunately, if I try to input a text, I do not get my defined msg, but:

```
'asd' must be a signed decimal number
```

Could someone explain why? Or rather, how I can force my input field to always validate with the @Digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JSF validation happens **after** conversion. If you input something that's not a number in the text field that's mapped to a BigDecimal in the backing bean, JSF will try to convert that into a BigDecimal and it will fail, of course. So the Hibernate Validator won't really have the chance to kick in. You'll need to localize the JSF conversion messages to achieve what you want.

I am not familiar with the @Digits annotation. But the [Hibernate Validator docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/) seem to indicate that it verifies if the number is using the expected amount of integer and fraction digits. So instead of inputting a text in the text field, try inputting a value that is not in the same format accepted by the validator (in your case, fraction = 2, integer = 13). So try inputting the value 123.123120 and see if you get the expected message.

Here's the hack to go all the way into the entities and get the annotations at the converter. First you need to create a custom converter for a number (in this case, BigDecimal):

```
@FacesConverter("MyBigDecimalConverter")
public class MyBigDecimalConverter extends NumberConverter {
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
    try {
        HtmlInputText it = (HtmlInputText) arg1;
        ValueExpression ve = it.getValueExpression("value");
        String expression = ve.getExpressionString();
        String field = expression.replaceAll("#\\{.*\\.", "");
        field = field.replace("}", "");
        String parent = expression.replace("." + field, "");
        ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = arg0.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        ValueExpression exp = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(arg0.getELContext(), parent, Object.class);
        Object obj = exp.getValue(arg0.getELContext());

        Digits d = null;    
        Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
        d = f.getAnnotation(Digits.class);
        return super.getAsObject(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    } catch (ConverterException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(d.message());
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        throw new ConverterException(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return super.getAsObject(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
    return super.getAsString(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}

}
```

And you need to use that converter in your page:

```
    <h:outputText value="#{someBean.someEntity.nome}" />
    <h:form>
        <p:inputText value="#{someBean.someEntity.someBigDecimal}" id="test">
            <f:converter converterId="MyBigDecimalConverter" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:message for="test"></h:message>
        <p:commandButton value="teste" process="@form" update="@form"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

I am using primeFaces components here, but you don't really need them.

What exactly is the converter doing? It is fetching the object in your bean that hold the value that the inputText refers to and the field name. Then, it finds the @Digits annotation for that field and reads its message. It asks for the NumericConverter to convert the String into a number. If that fails, it uses the message in the @Digits annotation for the error message.

Comment: yes when I make an input that passes the jsf I get the according hib validator msg.

Comment: I guess that answers your question then? I am glad I could help. Cheers

Comment: Not really. I'm still trying to force validation to hibernate, and to skip the jsf validation. As commented below, the f:validateBean does not work for me, even if I remove the tag completely. JSF seems to validate the mapping to a backing BigDecimal by default. And still I did not find anything to disable this specific.

Comment: The thing is that we're not really talking about validation at this point. We're talking about conversion and that's how JSF handles things. You won't be able to skip that. Like you said, if you input something that can be converted into a BigDecimal, then Hibernate Validator will be invoked. Otherwise, it just won't; there's no way around it. The easy way to change the message you're getting is to change that particular string in your resource bundle. Do you need help with that?

Comment: I just edited the answer. It's a huge hack; you might need to tweak a little bit here and there, but you get the idea.

Comment: tyvm! I think I can work around this with help of your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`<f:validateBean />`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validateBean.html) to delegates validation to the Bean Validation API (JSR 303)

```
<p:inputText value="#{payment.amount}" >
    <f:validateBean />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: This is strange. I tried this tag, but it does not work. Even if I remove the validation tag completely, there is still JSF validation taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this `<p:inputText>` tag but in vanilla JSF you could just:

```
<h:inputText id="price"
    value="#{movieController.movie.price}" redisplay="true"
    converterMessage="Please input a decimal">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="numberOfCopiesMessage" />
</h:inputText>
```

Notice the `converterMessage` attribute.

And while this might look like violating DRY (as you have a message in the entity already) it does not. Your model has nothing to do with a user submitting `'asd'` as an integer - it is really a *view* matter